# Fixing comment functionality for users to a post -- flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to link my User, Post, and Comment models so that after the comment is created, I want to be able to list all the comments (with the authors information) for the post.

In my jinja2 template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.content }}
    {% for comment in post.comments %}
        {{ comment.author.email }} 
        {{ comment.author.username }}
        {{ comment.content }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, I am unable to get the models linking correctly. Right now I have:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    ...

    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', primaryjoin="User.id==Post.author_id")

    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='author', primaryjoin="User.id==Comment.author_id")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}, {}, {}".format(self.username, self.email)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    ...

    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='post', lazy=True)


    def __repr__(self):
        return "Post(Title:'{}', Content:'{}')".format(self.title, self.content)


class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Comment({})".format(self.content)
```

However, that does not work. When trying it out in the terminal, post.comments returns "[ ]" (an empty list). Overall, the model relationships have been giving me a tough time.

****Edited****
This is an example of one of the ways I want to query:

```
@app.route("/myposts", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def myposts():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first_or_404()
    posts = Post.query.filter_by(author=user)\
            .order_by(Post.date_posted.desc())\
            .paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    return render_template('myposts.html', title='My Posts', posts=posts, user=user)
```

Comment: Why do you have the relationship from user--> comment ? Is that in case the user comments on a post? Also would you mind adding your routing / querying scripts too?

Comment: @calestini I don't entirely understand your question, but to clarify...A user creates a post with content. Then different users (or even themselves) can then comment on that post.

Comment: @calestini similar to a facebook post

Comment: It makes sense @aj3409. My question was because depending on how the objects are queried, it will only return comments by the `author_id=user_id (where user_id=author_id in post)`. That is, only comments by the author, that's why I was asking about how you are querying the models.

Comment: @calestini I added some of my routes. I want to be able to query any list of posts (based on the users who created the post, attributes of the post -- like title). Overall, I want to query the posts, and from the list of posts, display the comments (linked to the actual object of the author -- so I can display the author's username, email, profile pic, etc.)

Comment: Great, and a last question, have you tried breaking the relationship between Author and Comments and testing the results? If the comment is in a post and a post is related to an author, you shouldn't need that relationship right?

Comment: @calestini I was also planning on showing all the comments that a user has posted in an account page. And allowing them to link to the post and edit their comment...so wouldn't breaking the relationship affect that?

Comment: @calestini Also, wouldn't that not allow me to display the author's information from the User model in the comment section (i.e. username, email, profile pic, etc.)

Comment: @calestini by breaking up the relationship between Author and Comments, I can now print the comment content of a post. However, I cannot print any of the author's information. I want to link the comment object to the user object who created it similar to how the post object is linked to the user object that created it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can achieve getting all the information is by changing slightly your query to use explicit queries:

```py
posts = db.session.query(Post, User, Comments)\
            .join(User)\
            .join(Comments)\
            .filter(Post.author==user)\
            .order_by(Post.date_posted.desc())\
            .paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
```

Here I am assuming the relationship between `User` and `Comment` is no longer present. However, even if they are, some ways in which you can debug your relationships and gain more control of your queries is by:

1) Seeing the actual statement generated by the ORM:

```py
posts = db.session.query(Post, User, Comments)\
            .join(User)\
            .join(Comments)\
            .filter(Post.author==user)\
            .order_by(Post.date_posted.desc())

str(posts) # or posts.statement will print the query
```

2) Making your queries more explicit:

```py
posts = db.session.query(
                Post.id, Post.content, User.id, User.username, 
                Comments.date_posted, Comments.content.label('comm_content')
             )\
            .join(User)\ #you can even make this more explicit with .join(User, Post.author_id == User.id)
            .join(Comments)\ #same as above
            .filter(Post.author==user)\
            .order_by(Post.date_posted.desc())
```